# bash shell script automaticall add on file extension

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hello so today i was playing around with my shell script and figured to make it more user friendly i would make it so the file extension of file was automatically added.

for example say the user wants to search a file using grep but first they must type in thhe name of the file in this case lets say file.txt what i want to do is automatically add on the .txt so the user only needs to type in "file"

here is what i have so far but this does not work:

```
echo "Current .txt files "
        ls -R |grep .txt
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
                echo -n "Please select a file to search in: "
                read fileName
                file=$fileName.txt
```

i thought in this case since i am appending an extension on to the end of the variable name but this has not worked.

Comment: `grep .txt` will likely match more than you wanted; try `grep '\.txt$'. Generally, consider using `find` for enumerating files in directory subtrees, because it is much more flexible; the equivalent of your command using `find` is `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec basename {} +`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put quotes around it:

```
file="$filename.txt"
```

EDIT: As it happens, this answer is incorrect. See the comments below and the other answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need quotes on variable assignments ([reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters): "Word splitting is not performed [...]. Filename expansion is not performed.") -- whereever `$file` is used, that's where the quotes are needed.

Comment: obviously. You're describing http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion not variable assignment.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. If it's a variable whose contents contains spaces it'll work without the quotes. Interesting.

Comment: Here's a demo: `touch foobar: x=foo*; echo "$x"; echo $x`

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work. See below-

Contents of `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Current .txt files "
        ls -R |grep .txt
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
                echo -n "Please select a file to search in: "
                read fileName
                file=$fileName.txt

echo "You are searching for $file"
ls -l "$file"
```

Test run:

```
$ ./test.sh
Current .txt files
p1.txt
t1.txt
t2.txt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please select a file to search in: t2
You are searching for t2.txt
-rw-r----- 1 d1rld1f1 d1rld1f1 4 Apr 20 12:41 t2.txt
$
```

BTW, it is generally advisable to enclose variable names in double quotes. This prevents reinterpretation of all special characters within the quoted string.

Comment: Note that `ls -R | grep .txt` returns text files anywhere in the current folder's _subtree_ , whereas your test run with `ls -l` only happens to work if the specified text file is _directly_ in the current folder.